# Running reduce function twice on an array ? results in an undefined node js

Tags: node.js

I am having issues with node js. I am thinking this has to do with how the code runs async.
Is it because that the reduce function is running asynchronously ?
If so what is the idiomatic pattern I must follow inorder to run these function one after another?

I am trying to run reduce operation twice and the second time I am getting an undefined

function hello () {

```
var values = [
    {"a": 1},
    {"b": 2},
    {"c": 3},
    {"d": 4},
    {"b": 5},
    {"a": 6},
    {"a": 7},
    {"b": 8},
    {"c": 9},
    {"d": 10}
];

var kvList = values.reduce(function (result, element) {

    var key = Object.keys(element);
    var val = element[key];

    // if undefined create an array.
    result[key] = result[key] || [];
    result[key].push(val);

    return result;

}, []);

console.log(kvList);
console.log(kvList[0]); // becomes undefined here.
var pairs = kvList.reduce(function (result, element) {

    console.log("HELLO");
    var key = Object.keys(element)[0];

    console.log(element);

    var subArray = element[key];

    var total = subArray.reduce(function (result, element) {
        return result + element;
    }, 0);

    result[key] = total;
    return result;

}, []);

console.log(pairs);
```

};

hello();

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce()` does not run asynchronously.

Comment: It if does not than why is it that I get an undefined after printing the result ?, and trying to operate on the kvList ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.reduce()` does not run asynchronously.

The issue is that `.reduce()` operates on array elements (sequentially numbered elements that are accessed via a numeric index starting at `0`).  Your first array has array elements.  The result of your first `.reduce()` however is an array object, but has only properties such as 'a', 'b', 'c' and and no actual array elements.  For example, after your first `.reduce()` operation, `kvList.length === 0` so the second `.reduce()` does not cycle through the elements like you want it to.

The culprit in the first `.reduce()` loop are these lines of code:

```
// if undefined create an array.
result[key] = result[key] || [];
result[key].push(val);
```

This adds a property to `result` with the property name `key`.  It does not actually add an element to the array so the second `.reduce()` then has no array elements to operate on.

---

OK, now that you've shown the desired result, this generates that result:

```
var values = [
    {"a": 1}, {"b": 2}, {"c": 3}, {"d": 4}, {"b": 5},
    {"a": 6}, {"a": 7}, {"b": 8}, {"c": 9}, {"d": 10}
];

var dict = {};
values.forEach(function(obj) {
    // iterate the properties of each object in the array
    for (var prop in obj) {
        // if not already in the dict, add an empty array to the dict for this property name
        if (!(prop in dict)) {
            dict[prop] = [];
        }
        // add this number to the array for this dict entry
        dict[prop].push(obj[prop]);
    }
});

// dict is {"a":[1,6,7],"b":[2,5,8],"c":[3,9],"d":[4,10]}

// process back into an array
var result = [];
// iterate each property in the dict
for (var prop in dict) {
    // create an object that is of this form {prop: [val1, val2, val3]}
    // and put it in the result array
    var temp = {};
    temp[prop] = dict[prop];
    result.push(temp);
}

// result is [{"a":[1,6,7]},{"b":[2,5,8]},{"c":[3,9]},{"d":[4,10]}]
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/q8u208y4/

FYI, your data structures of an object with a single key are somewhat weird and hard to work with.  I'm wondering why the final result isn't what's in dict which is actually easier to work with in code since you can just iterate the properties directly to get each property and corresponding array.

Comment: ic I was trying to return dictionaries ? how do I do that?  :S

Comment: I can explain why your code doesn't work properly, but I don't know what you're trying to achieve so I'm not sure exactly what else to suggest.  Can you explain in words what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to get this result
[ {a: [ 1, 6, 7 ]}, {b: [ 2, 5, 8 ]}, {c: [ 3, 9 ]}, {d: [ 4, 10 ]} ]

Comment: I am trying to do a mapreduce, then I am gonna reduce it down to a list of single values.

Comment: There is an easier way in which you do {"key": "x","value":"h"} ... then build the result from there but I would be using dictionaries incorrectly ?

Comment: @GeorgeHost - one way to do it is in my answer.  Also, I'm wondering why you want the result you've specified because single property objects are a pain to work with in javascript if you don't already know the property names in each object.  I'm wondering why you don't just want the value I end up with in `dict` after my first pass because it's way easier to work with.

Comment: Okay so, I wanted able to iterate over  [{a: [ 1, 6, 7 ]}, {b: [ 2, 5, 8 ]}, {c: [ 3, 9 ]}, {d: [ 4, 10 ]}] using only a reduce, without using an for.each or for in loops and create transform the data with only those functions as a restriction. I wanted to match up the keys, to group the values with the corresponding keys using only reduce.

Comment: @GeorgeHost - you can't iterate over that using only `.reduce()`.  That iterates only the array elements.  But, the properties and values you are interested in are nested inside those objects so you have to iterate the array to get each object and then iterate the properties on each object (which you can't use `.reduce()` for since it only works on actual arrays) to get the keys and values.

Comment: I have a sorta solution.
Store the result of the reduce as a dictionary so { a: [ 1, 6, 7 ], b: [ 2, 5, 8 ], c: [ 3, 9 ], d: [ 4, 10 ] }
Then run var result = Object.keys(a_list).reduce(function(result,key){
// use key here obtain array and reduce the array and return the result with the key
})

Comment: @GeorgeHost - This is a bad data structure for javascript because of the extra nested iteration that is required.  Single property objects are usually a bad data structure in javascript, particular when the property is different in every object.  Whenever I see that, my first thought is that the data is laid out in a painful way to use and could likely be organized in a much easier way.

Comment: @GeorgeHost - what's wrong with the solution I put in my answer?

Comment: Oh nothing I am gonna give you the credit thanks alot I realized I made a stupid mistake by associating a property to the array, yeah I am only allowed reduce thats all.

Comment: @GeorgeHost - if you really want to use `.reduce()` for the outer array iteration, you can do that like here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/58pmwrog/, but honestly I think it's more complex than using `.each()` like I did in my first implementation.

Comment: Is there a way to get the result to result = [{"a":[1,6,7]},{"b":[2,5,8]},{"c":[3,9]},{"d":[4,10]}] without having to run the second loop ?

Comment: By only using the reduce function above? thats is the problem on my mind.

Comment: @GeorgeHost - I think I've explained several times, that your original data structure has two levels of data (an array and properties on embedded objects).  You HAVE to use two nested levels of iteration to get to the data.  The main problem is that the first data structure is flawed.  Something like this would be much easier in one level of iteration: `[["a", 1], ["b", 2],["c", 3]]` or even [{prop: "a", val: 1}, {prop: "b", val: 2, {prop: "c", val: 3}].  Then, you could use a single `.reduce()` because the data is all accessible with one level of iteration.

Comment: @GeorgeHost - And, this is a much better output result: `{"a":[1,6,7],"b":[2,5,8],"c":[3,9],"d":[4,10]}` which is fully descriptive, but easier to produce (only the first part of my solution is required to produce this) and easier to use in Javascript (can get to all the data in one array iteration).  Avoid  objects with only a single, unknown property in Javascript.  They are a pain to use and don't offer anything that a simpler data structure to use doesn't also offer.

Comment: Alright haha, I guess applying python based techniques don't work here thanks again!